# Social Plugin only visible when the user is logged in to Facebook. How Do I Make The Fans Show All The Time?

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-social-plugins

My site is this [one](http://sincityclubconnect.com) and if your not logged into Facebook you won't see the social plugin show all my facebook fans. I'm not sure if the app is setup wrong and I have used html, xfmbl, and Iframe but I get the same results which leads me to believe it might be the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at it when not logged in, I get a prompt asking me to "login to see this content".  This appears to be working as I'd expect it to.